# How to add Image at the particular area in a template image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-graphics

This is a template image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ME6A.jpg) in which multiple circular area are available. we need, when we click on any circular area (one by one ) then gallery should be open and after selecting the image from gallery that image should be shown on the selected circular area. 
       Please provide me any link or demo for my problem. i am stucking here.

Thanks!

Comment: Show me your coding till now what you tried?

Comment: Are circular images in tableView or View?

Comment: Please see the Template Image at the geven link

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9ME6A.jpg

Comment: I saw that.I ask you in which one did you set the images?

Comment: I dont make Any Code till now Because I dont Find any Good Logic To do it.So please give me a solution if u can

Comment: In all Circular area in which user tap one by one

Comment: Did you make circular images in coding?

Comment: I go lunch now.I will help you after 15 minutes.

Comment: no Actually the template Image is Coming From Api And Circles may be anywhere in the whole screen (Not at Fixe Position)

Comment: ok f9 i am also going for lunch

Comment: In design How do you set the images?

Comment: Do you have only 5 images?

Comment: If you give response only we can give better solution otherwise it is not possible.

Comment: no there is no only five images. its may be different numbers.

Comment: Five images are static but numbers are different?

Comment: no, it may be any numbers of images in any where in the whole screen

Comment: this template is just only for demo purpose

Comment: Ok then If I give sample demo coding for the 5 images,can you understand that?

Comment: yes please provide me

Comment: I wrote code for all imageviews.Is it okey for you?

Comment: As i told you that they are circular area in an image (they are  Not 5 imageviews ). if you find the frame of those areas and create imageviews at those location then it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a viewController with 5 "UIImageView" views. Arrange as you need it
2. Place there your smile images.
3. Add UITapGestureRecognizer into every UIImageView and catch them
4. Open UIImagePicker and make your VC as a delegate
5. Catch user selected picture event and place the image to your concrete UIImageView

Comment: Actually the template image is not static it is coming from backend so smile circular area can be lies anywhere in the template Image and number of circles also can be different like - 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 etc

Answer (score 0):

You should get the mapping(position and dimensions) of circular images in the template image from the backend and use those values for displaying circles and selecting images from gallery.

If you are getting a single image with all circles, then it will be very difficult to identify all the circles(using complex algorithms) in the single image.

If the backend is able to provide the mapping data, first method is the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

in ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView5;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
{
  UIImageView *imageviewPick;
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize imageView1,imageView2,imageView3,imageView4,imageView5;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

imageView1.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView1.frame.size.height / 2;
imageView1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
imageView1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
imageView1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

imageView2.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView2.frame.size.height / 2;
imageView2.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
imageView2.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
imageView2.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

imageView3.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView3.frame.size.height / 2;
imageView3.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
imageView3.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
imageView3.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

imageView4.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView4.frame.size.height / 2;
imageView4.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
imageView4.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
imageView4.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

imageView5.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView5.frame.size.height / 2;
imageView5.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
imageView5.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
imageView5.layer.masksToBounds = YES;



UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapImageOne:)];
tap1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapImageTwo:)];
tap2.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap3 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapImageThree:)];
tap3.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap4 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapImageFour:)];
tap4.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap5 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapImageFive:)];
tap4.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;


imageView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
imageView2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
imageView3.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
imageView4.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
imageView5.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


[imageView1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
[imageView2 addGestureRecognizer:tap2];
[imageView3 addGestureRecognizer:tap3];
[imageView4 addGestureRecognizer:tap4];
[imageView5 addGestureRecognizer:tap5];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)tapImageOne:(UIGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
  imageviewPick = (UIImageView *)tapGesture.view;
  [self showGallery];
}
-(void)tapImageTwo:(UIGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
  imageviewPick = (UIImageView *)tapGesture.view;
  [self showGallery];
}
-(void)tapImageThree:(UIGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
   imageviewPick = (UIImageView *)tapGesture.view;
   [self showGallery];
}
-(void)tapImageFour:(UIGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
  imageviewPick = (UIImageView *)tapGesture.view;
  [self showGallery];
}
-(void)tapImageFive:(UIGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
  imageviewPick = (UIImageView *)tapGesture.view;
  [self showGallery];
}

-(void)showGallery
{
   UIImagePickerController *pickImage = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
   pickImage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   pickImage.delegate = self;
   [self presentViewController:pickImage animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
   UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   imageviewPick.image = image;
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```