# How can we get the frame of the given Circles in the image

Tags: ios, xcode, object, core-graphics

In this image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6zgo.jpg) there are multiple Circular Area, i need to find the exact frame ( x,y, width,height) of these circles(emozi's). please give me a demo or link.
    I am stucking Here,
thanks

Comment: same question again ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560286/how-to-add-image-at-the-particular-area-in-a-template-image

Comment: what did you use to create these images. Are you using imageView or uiview ?

Comment: Actually this is a full image and i need that, when user tap on the given circles then gallery should be open. user select the image from gallery then selectd image should be drawn into the selected circle.

Comment: Why dont you use the Preview app in your mac? Open the image in it, then draw rectangles around whatever you want to find the frame for?

Comment: This is required in an ios app. we need to draw the user selected image from galery on the given image and send it to backend.

Comment: you can use gesture on imageView and get action for gesture and get frame with using `CGRectGetMaxX(yourView.frame) CGRectGetMaxY(yourView.frame)`

Comment: please give me a solution for how to get the frame of the given circles After that i will solve my problem